# Not able to download base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created Dockerfile and when I run command `docker build -f Dockerfile -t application:0.0.1-snapshot .` on the server rhel 7.6 (Maipo)  then I am getting below error :

> Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:8
>
> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority

Comment: It seems you want to pull the image from a private registry, so you need to log in first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problems with resolving public Certificate Authorities.
You should try to install/reinstall package `ca-certificates` on your target host, e.g. using apt:

`sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates`

After that, restart docker daemon:

`sudo service docker restart`

Comment: When I run above script :  sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates   ; I am getting error : sudo: apt: command not found